# Issue in .Net Core unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, console-application

I have a console app which contains 2 classes and create unit test project with it

```
class Program
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Triangle Type Test :-\n----------------------------\n\n");
        Trigonometric.TrianlgeSidesInput(12, 12, 12);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Trigonometric.TrianlgeSidesInput(12, 12, 15);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Trigonometric.TrianlgeSidesInput(12, 20, 25);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Trigonometric
{
    public static double eqSide1, eqSide2, eqSide3;
    public static void TrianlgeSidesInput(double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        string TriangleType = "";
        if ((side1 == side2) && (side1 == side3))
        {
            TriangleType = "Equilateral";
        }
        else if ((side1 == side2) || (side1 == side3) || (side2 == side3))
        {
            TriangleType = "Isosceles";
            eqSide1 = side1; eqSide2 = side2; eqSide3 = side3;
        }
        else
        {
            TriangleType = "Scalene";
        }

        switch (TriangleType)
        {
            case "Equilateral":
                Console.WriteLine("It is Equilateral Traingle ! Reason: It's all sides are equal.\n\n\t i. e. {0}=={1}==                                 {2}", side1, side2, side3);
                Console.WriteLine("For Next : Press Enter \n");

                break;

            case "Isosceles":
                Console.WriteLine("It is Isosceles Traingle ! Reason: It's two sides are equal.");
                Console.WriteLine("For Next : Press Enter \n");
                break;

            case "Scalene":
                Console.WriteLine("It is Scalene Traingle ! Reason: It's all sides have different lenght !!");
                Console.WriteLine("For Next : Press Enter \n");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry ! Try Again !");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

packages in .csproject

```
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
MSTest.TestAdapter
MSTest.TestFramework
coverlet.collector
```

It is not recognizing Test Class and Test Method. The test project is created dotnet new mstest command and errors exists in build in template
kindly help me in resolving this issue

Comment: "It is not recognizing Test Class and Test Method" - and who is "It"? "errors exists in build in template " - and what are the errors?

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: /Users/zahoorghani/Desktop/practice/unit-testing-using-mstest/PrimeService/PrimeService.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net20 1.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature validity period has expired.
It is showing this error

Comment: Can you share the test class code?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the package version. Latest version appear to be 1.0.2.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies